# VB.NET: Adding binary ressource file to project which has to be referenced by URI later

Tags: vb.net, uri

I coded a color-conversion routine (see below) to calculate integer color values from CMYK values (analogous the existing RGB-Function) which relies on a external color profile file (ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc) for conversion.
 I like to include this file with my project to be used at run-time. The used function (System.Windows.Media.Color.FromValues) needs an URI to the file as second parameter to work.
I tested the function to work with an absolute path to the file in the development environment but this won't work in an production environment.

```
Public Function CMYK(ByVal Cyan As Integer, ByVal Magenta As Integer, ByVal Yellow As Integer, ByVal BlackKey As Integer) As Integer
    '*** Die CMYK-Werte müssen in Prozent sein!
    If Cyan < 0 OrElse Magenta < 0 OrElse Yellow < 0 OrElse BlackKey < 0 OrElse
       Cyan > 100 OrElse Magenta > 100 OrElse Yellow > 100 OrElse BlackKey > 100 Then Return 0
    Dim snaColorValues() As Single = {Cyan / 100, Magenta / 100, Yellow / 100, BlackKey / 100}
    Dim oColor As System.Windows.Media.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromValues(snaColorValues, New Uri("C:\Users\obr\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NTTools_Powerpoint\NTTools_Powerpoint\Resources\ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"))
    Return Information.RGB(oColor.R, oColor.G, oColor.B)
End Function
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that file as an embedded binary file resource. It will be accessible in your code under `My.Resources.TheNameYouUsed` as `Byte()`.

Then, before running the function that will need it, dump that byte array to a file:

```
Dim iccFilePath As String = "C:\Users\obr\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NTTools_Powerpoint\NTTools_Powerpoint\Resources\ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(iccFilePath, My.Resources.TheNameYouUsed)
```